# Яка різниця між словами "монумент", "скульптура", "статуя"?

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

Монумент, скульптура, статуя - чи є тотожними ці слова, як і коли вживати їх у тексті?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Інколи ці слова сплутують при вживанні, тому слід пам'ятати, що скульптура - це 1) один з видів мистецтва; 2) витвір цього мистецтва; 3) сукупність таких витворів. Статуя - скульптурне зображення постаті, яке має повний об'єм. Монумент - великий пам'ятник, споруда на честь видатної особи чи визначної події. За А.П.Коваль "Культура української мови".